# Can I access :NEW and :OLD dynamically in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql, triggers

I am trying to somehow dynamically access :NEW and :OLD in Oracle SQL. I know that this isn't possible, but I am searching for an easier (and less messier) way than just creating the script for creating the trigger and executing it. My code so far:

```
--Creating a new type called COLUMN_ARRAY to save multiple column names 
--(up to 50) dynamically in an array.

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE COLUMN_ARRAY AS VARRAY(50) OF VARCHAR2(30);
/

--Creating a procedure which is called in the trigger. 
--It inserts the given values into a changelog table.

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRO_CL(
    var_changelogTable VARCHAR2,
    var_table          VARCHAR2,
    var_column         VARCHAR2,
    var_oldValue       VARCHAR2,
    var_newValue       VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '    
INSERT    
INTO '||var_changelogTable||' VALUES      
(        
'''',        
SYSTIMESTAMP,        
'''||var_table||''',        
'''||var_column||''',
'''||var_oldValue||''',        
'''||var_newValue||'''      
)';
END;
/
```

This creates the trigger. Right now, I iterate over my array and use the tablenames to dynamically initialize the variables that are passed to the procedure, this doesn't work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_CL BEFORE
  INSERT OR
  UPDATE OR
  DELETE ON TESTTABLE FOR EACH ROW DECLARE
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- These values have to be put in by a user
  var_changelogTable VARCHAR2(30) := 'CHANGELOGTABLE';
  var_table            VARCHAR2(30) := 'TESTTABLE';
  var_columns COLUMN_ARRAY          := COLUMN_ARRAY('TEST1', 'TEST2');
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- These values are dynamic and are produced by the trigger
  var_column   VARCHAR2(30);
  var_oldValue VARCHAR2(4000);
  var_newValue VARCHAR2(4000);
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..var_columns.count
    LOOP
      -- Dynamic variables are initialized
      var_column := var_columns(i);
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'var_oldValue := :OLD.'||var_column;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'var_newValue := :NEW.'||var_column;
      -- The Procedure only is called when the old and new values are different
      IF var_oldValue != var_newValue THEN
        PRO_CL(var_changelogTable, var_table, var_column, var_oldValue, var_newValue);
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  END;
  /
```

So my question is: Is there any way to create this trigger dynamically, or do I have to use the messy way and dynamically create a script which then creates the trigger?

Comment: you can try using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871650/using-old-and-new-object-for-dynamic-operations-inside-trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you can create the trigger itself dynamically looping over *user_tab_columns* (for each column there will be 1 line with call to PRO_CL_BESTNR)
2. oldValue != newValue will not cover NULL value without change, you should pass both values to the log procedure and this shall compare them